# Is it possible to create new rows in SAS with respect to population density?

Tags: sas

Is it possible to create a data set with new rows proportional to population density? For instance, if I have population density of a certain state, is it possible to create empty rows where the number of rows are proportional to its population density?

```
zip   density
75001 2551
75002 944
75006 2625
75007 4209
75009 51
```

Comment: Why is this labeled SQL?

Comment: Use the data step command in SAS.  This is not a SQL question.  By the way, if you are just trying to weight results, most SAS procs accept a frequency variable.

Comment: "to create empty rows where the number of rows are proportional to its population density"

Comment: What does this have to do with "database design" ?  Database design is the process of specifying logical and/or physical parts of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this...

```
data dat;
input 
 zip 
 density;
cards; 
75001 2551
75002 944
75006 2625
75007 4209
75009 51
run; 



data new; 
  set dat; 
  by zip;
  if first.zip then do; 
    do i= 1 to density;
        output; 
    end; 
  end; 
Run;
```